# Korean historical reincarnation manhwa where the female lead used to be a traditional medicine doctor

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Does anyone know the name of this reincarnation historical Korean manhwa (Joseon dynasty era) where the female lead is reincarnated as a 12 year old? In her previous life she was a traditional medicine doctor. It has around 12 chapters out right now. The first chapter shows her doing target practice with arrows with her older brother. I read it on mangaowl. She looks like an average 12 yr old child with black hair.

Comment: Could this be *The Era of Female Doctor*. It's surprisingly hard to find a legitimate link for you to look at; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceqbj.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about Falling Flower, Flowing Water. According to [Anime Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/falling-flower-flowing-water):

> Kim Sojin lived an intense everyday life as an oriental doctor. However, after losing her life in a fire accident, she woke up again in the Goguryeo period as the daughter of the Jeolnobu Yeon Clan 'Yeon Woohee.' Although she was born into a noble family, war breaks out every day in this era. And now that she's twelve, she's going through a political marriage?! Of all things, my marriage partner is someone who everybody in South Korea knows about, that 'Gwanggaeto The Great'?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] this answer to explain why you think this is the correct manga though, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question?